# Mysql JOIN tables with preference and a GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, find-in-set

I'm working on an file/image database. 
I have one table that indexes the file names and attaches them to an 'album'

```
FILES TABLE
file_id | file_name | album_id
1       | image x   |  2
2       | image y   |  2
```

The second table stores the location and various sizes of the files

```
SOURCE TABLE
source_id | file_id | source_size | source_url
1         |  1      | original    | //... 
2         |  1      | thumbnail   | //... 
3         |  2      | original    | //... 
4         |  3      | original    | //...
```

Currently the 'source_size' column is listed as text (original, thumbnail, preview etc..).

I'm struggling to query the tables with a preference on the source_size while still returning all files within that album.

So far it looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
f.*, s.*
FROM source s
INNER JOIN files f ON f.file_id=s.file_id 
WHERE f.album_id="2" 
GROUP BY s.file_id
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(s.source_size,"thumbnail, original") DESC
```

I would like it to return the source_id of the file in thumbnail format first but failing that simply return the original size file where it does not find a match.

In future queries it may be with a preference of originals or previews.

Comment: So you want all files regardless of whether they're thumbnail or original, but you want to sort by thumbnail first?

Comment: Yes, if there is a thumbnail - show that, if no thumbnail but there is a preview show that, then finally if no preview simply show the original file.

Comment: assuming they won't have multiple thumbnails or originals and there is no other type.... `select f.*, coalesce(s_thumb.source_url, s_orig.source_url) as source_url from files f left outer join source s_thumb on s_thumb.file_id = f.file_id and s_thumb.source_size='thumbnail'  left outer join source s_orig on s_orig.file_id = f.file_id and s_orig.source_size='original'`

Comment: that's not the ideal way to do that, though.  bc scalability.  i would [look into how mysql does ranking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) and use a case statement to set your source size preferences and then take the top for each group by file_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for the moment but not sure if it's right...

```
    SELECT 
    f.*, fs*
    FROM files f
    INNER JOIN (SELECT s.* FROM file_source s ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(s.source_size,"thumbnail, original") DESC) fs ON f.file_id=fs.file_id 
    WHERE f.album_id="2" 
    GROUP BY f.file_id
    ORDER BY f.file_id DESC
```